# Smart Table: Use Bootstrap Datetime-Picker with AngularJs as Filter

Tags: angularjs, filtering, angular-ui-bootstrap, datetimepicker, smart-table

I'm using AngularJS and Smart Table to show items from Database and Filter the items by Date. I want to use a Datetimepicker (Bootsrap.UI http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/)

My Problem is if I type the text into the input of the Datetime-element it works but if I select a date via Datetimepicker, the text changes but the Filter is not set.

Is there any way to give the smart-table the picked Filter?

My Table Head looks like this:

```
 <table st-table="feedBacks" st-pipe="callServer"
                   class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover table-highlight table-checkable">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th style="width: 160px">Datum</th>
                        <th>Produkt</th>
                        <th>Version</th>
                        <th>Plattform</th>
                        <th>FeedBack</th>
                        <th style="width: 125px">Option</th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th>
                            <p class="input-group">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control"
                                       datepicker-popup="{{format}}" ng-model="dt"
                                       is-open="opened" datepicker-options="dateOptions"
                                       ng-required="true"
                                       close-text="Close" st-search="Timestamp" id="dateFilter" />
                                <span class="input-group-btn">
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="openDate($event)"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i></button>
                                </span>
                            </p>
                        </th>
                        <th><input st-search="ApiKey.Product.ProductName" /></th>
                        <th><input st-search="ApiKey.ProductVersion" /></th>
                        <th>
                            <div class="btn-group">
                                <button class="btn btn-default btn-xs" st-plattform-filter="" st-plattform-filter-column="Plattform">
                                    <span class="fa fa-reorder"></span>
                                </button>
                                <button class="btn btn-default btn-xs" st-plattform-filter="0" st-plattform-filter-column="Plattform">
                                    <span class="fa fa-android"></span>
                                </button>
                                <button class="btn btn-default btn-xs" st-plattform-filter="1" st-plattform-filter-column="Plattform">
                                    <span class="fa fa-windows"></span>
                                </button>
                                <button class="btn btn-default btn-xs" st-plattform-filter="2" st-plattform-filter-column="Plattform">
                                    <span class="fa fa-apple"></span>
                                </button>
                            </div>
                        </th>
                        <th></th>
                        <th></th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
```

Comment: have you got the answer for this?

Comment: I've implemented this using Smart-table and dateRangePicker if it's any help? Let me know and I'll post the code.

Comment: hi, I have same problem, plz post the example , thanks

Answer (score 0):

I know this is not elegant solution But it will work.

**st-input-event="focus"**

```
<input st-input-event="focus" st-search="end_time" class="input-sm form-control" type="text" ng-model="end_time" is-open="status.end_time_open" close-text="Close" uib-datepicker-popup="yyyy-MM-dd" datepicker-options="dateOptions" />
```

Answer (score 0):

i use this pluging https://github.com/fragaria/angular-daterangepicker
as i like the date range and its pure angular.

hope it helps you :)

my html:

```
 <div ng-controller="dateRange" class="text-right">
                            <st-date-range start="dateRange.start" end="dateRange.end"></st-date-range>
                            <ta-date-range-picker class="well" ng-model="dateRange" ranges="customRanges" callback="dateRangeupdate(dateRange)"></ta-date-range-picker>
                        </div>
```

Directive:

```
.directive('stDateRange', ['$timeout', function ($timeout) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        require: '^stTable',
        scope: {
            start: '=',
            end: '='
        },

        link: function (scope, element, attr, table) {
            var query = {};
            var predicateName = attr.predicate;

            scope.$watch('start', function () {
                if (scope.start) {
                    query.start = moment(scope.start).format('YYYY-MM-DD');
                }
                if (scope.end) {
                    query.end = moment(scope.end).format('YYYY-MM-DD');
                }
                table.search(query, predicateName);
            });
        }
    }
    }])
```

Controller

```
//Select range options
$scope.customRanges = [
    {
        label: "This week",
        range: moment().range(
            moment().startOf("week").startOf("day"),
            moment().endOf("week").startOf("day")
        )
    },
    {
        label: "Last month",
        range: moment().range(
            moment().add(-1, "month").startOf("month").startOf("day"),
            moment().add(-1, "month").endOf("month").startOf("day")
        )
    },
    {
        label: "This month",
        range: moment().range(
            moment().startOf("month").startOf("day"),
            moment().endOf("month").startOf("day")
        )
    },
    {
        label: "This year",
        range: moment().range(
            moment().startOf("year").startOf("day"),
            moment().endOf("year").startOf("day")
        )
    },
    {
        label: "Last year",
        range: moment().range(
            moment().startOf("year").add(-1, "year").startOf("day"),
            moment().add(-1, "year").endOf("year").startOf("day")
        )
    }
];

$scope.mycallback = "None";
$scope.dateRangeChanged = function () {
    $scope.mycallback = " from " + $scope.dateRange.start.format("LL") + " to " + $scope.dateRange.end.format("LL");
}


}]);
```

Comment: Can you add please plunker? This is not working for me. But I have the same trouble.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old. But if anybody is struggling to get this on Angular 1.6 here's my answer:

Directive:

```
var app = angular.module("datePickerFilter", []);

app.directive("datePickerFilter", function () {

  function link(scope, element, attr, table) {


scope.$watch('dateToFilter', function () {

  //check if is different from null
  if (scope.dateToFilter) {
    //format if it's not null
    var formatedDate = moment(scope.dateToFilter).format('YYYY-MM-DD');
    table.search(formatedDate, scope.stSearch);
  }
  //trigger the search
  table.search(formatedDate, scope.stSearch);
});

//Opciones para input de fecha
scope.dateOptions = {
  formatYear: 'yy',
  startingDay: 1
};

scope.dateFormat = 'yyyy-MM-dd';
scope.altInputFormats = ['M!/d!/yyyy'];
scope.dateInputOpened = false;

scope.openDateInput = function () {
  scope.dateInputOpened = true;
};


}



return {
    scope: {
      stSearch: "="
    },
    link: link,
    restrict: "E",
    //We need this directive to be under a stTable directive instance
    require: "^stTable",
    template:


 ` <div class="input-group">
      <input class="form-control" type="text" uib-datepicker-popup="{{format}}" is-open="dateInputOpened"
          ng-model="dateToFilter" datepicker-options="dateOptions" close-text="Cerrar"
          alt-input-formats="altInputFormats" ng-click="openDateInput()" ng-focus="openDateInput()" />
      <span class="input-group-btn">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="openDateInput()">
              <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i>
          </button>
      </span>
  </div>`


 };

});
```

HTML:

```
<date-picker-filter st-search="'nameOfDateFieldToFilter'"></date-picker-filter>
```